# Footer inside a div Bootstrap 5

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to do the following in HTML with Bootstrap 5 but I can't, can someone help me?
[image]

This is the final idea but only have problem with the first image. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try this logic :

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
        <link
          href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <nav class="bg-dark my-2 py-3">
          <h2 class="text-light text-center">Navbar</h2>
        </nav>
    
        <div
          class="container bg-light my-4 py-4 d-flex justify-content-between flex-column"
          style="height: auto; min-height: 600px"
        >
          <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <!--  -->
            <div
              class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 m-2"
              style="
                background-color: beige;
                min-width: 400px;
                min-height: 300px;
                height: auto;
              "
            >
              <div class="row h-100">
                <div
                  class="col-12 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"
                >
                  <p class="text-muted">Another div with content</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-end align-items-end mb-2">
                  <input type="checkbox" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- / -->
            <!--  -->
            <div
              class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 m-2"
              style="
                background-color: beige;
                min-width: 400px;
                min-height: 300px;
                height: auto;
              "
            >
              <div class="row h-100">
                <div
                  class="col-12 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"
                >
                  <p class="text-muted">Another div with content</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-end align-items-end mb-2">
                  <input type="checkbox" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- / -->
            <!--  -->
            <div
              class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 m-2"
              style="
                background-color: beige;
                min-width: 400px;
                min-height: 300px;
                height: auto;
              "
            >
              <div class="row h-100">
                <div
                  class="col-12 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"
                >
                  <p class="text-muted">Another div with content</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-end align-items-end mb-2">
                  <input type="checkbox" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- / -->
          </div>
    
          <div class="row">
            <h2>Main Container</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```